# Remcom.exe connection error

Tags: teamcity, nant

When we start a build task from TeamCity, we get the following error from Remcom.exe. But we can run Remcom.exe task within the TeamCity agent machine directly without any problem. What shoud be the problem?

```
[exec] Remote Command Executor
[exec] Copyright 2006 The WiseGuyz [ http://talhatariq.wordpress.com ] 
[exec] Author: Talha Tariq [talha.tariq@gmail.com]
[exec] Initiating Connection to Remote Service . . . Failed
[exec] Couldn't connect to \\FuncTests\ADMIN$
[exec] Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again
```

Thanks for your prompt replies.

Comment: As it says in the error message: you already have an open SMB connection to FuncTests. Bear in mind that Windows might not close an SMB connection until you actually restart.

Comment: After getting the error for the first time, restarted both the TeamCity agent machine and functests remote machine. Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try "net use" to see the list of connections (active or not)?

```
C:\> net use
New connections will be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote       Network

-------------------------------------------------------------
OK           N:        \\...
Disconnected X:        \\...        Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

Then you can use "net use ... /delete" to remove the conflicting connection:

```
C:\> net use X: /delete
X: was deleted successfully.
```